# verificar campo email y password - react native

Tags: react-native

buen dia, tengo un fetch donde traigo mis datos de mi api, todo funciona pero necesito validar un if y que si email y password son correcto entren el if, ya que tengo el ejemplo pero con datos predeterminados `correo == "pepe@gmail.com" && password == "12345678"`

```js
  await fetch('https://www.miweb.com/apiPlooy/usuarios/login.php',
            {
              method:'POST',
              headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-Type': 'application/json'
         
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({"email":correo, "password" : password})
            }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(resData => {
               if(correo == "pepe@gmail.com" && password == "12345678") {
                Alert.alert(resData.message)
               }else{
                Alert.alert("no es pepe")
               }
           
             console.log(resData);
                    
            });
            
           }catch (error) {
            dispatch({type: 'addError',
            payload: error.response.data.msg || 'Información incorrecta'})
           }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tienes un catch sin un try y no debería ser el frontend quien manege la validación del usuario y contraseña sino el backend. Pero aqui tienes una función que hace una especie de validación para obtener información de una API.

Y tienes un pequeño typo en el header 'Content-Type' lo escribiste en minúscula, quizás eso pudo ser un problema.

```js
async function query(email, password){
  try{
    await fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: {email, password}
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resData => {
         if(email === 'as' && password === '123'){
            console.log(resData);
         }else{
            throw "No permitido"  
         }
        });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

query('asd', '123')
```

Comment: buen dia, pero en  if(email === 'as' && password === '123') necesito que sea por  ejemplo email=true osea que si el email es correcto y el password , ingrese al if y no colocar datos predeterminados como es : as y 123

Comment: Ok ya te entiendo, eso lo debe hacer el backend, pero si es imperativo que se haga desde el frontend, entonces en el body de la consulta solicita al usuario, por lo general envias el id o el correo del usuario y luego el backend te devuelve toda la información del usuario. Luego confirmas la respuesta haciendo "if(resData.email == email && resData.password == password) { console.log(true) }"